# Where to get a fireplace door retaining clip

Tags: fireplace, hardware

I have glass doors on my wood burning fireplace. The doors don't want to stay fully closed and I think the reason why is that the clips that hold them in have deteriorated over the years.

I've looked at the big box stores to try and find new hardware like the attached but I'm not having any luck. The way they fit is that they sit toward the top of the door. A screw goes through the clip from the inside of the door and then a brass knob acts as the nut on the outside of the door. The curved part you can see in the side profile is what is supposed to catch the top of the door frame to hold the door closed.

Does anybody know if this type of clip has a specific name or where I can order a couple?

Pictures of the clip and how it engages with the door frame:

[image: View Side Profile of the clip]

[image: View Side Profile of the clip]

[image: View of how the Clip engages the door frame]

Comment: I might suggest you also post pictures of how the clip is attached and engages the doors. My fireplace door hardware looks *nothing like this* and somehow I doubt it's very standardized, but pictures of how it functions entirely might enable someone to find a suitable substitute.

Comment: You'll need to come up with a brand name. Fireplaces are very proprietary, as Sidney said. Do post photos showing more context.

Comment: Hi Sidney, Isherwood,

I added a picture of how the clip engages the doors in an edit to the original post. Looking around the fireplace I don't see anything that tells me a brand or model. This fireplace was put in by the builder of the house in the early 80's and I'm not the original owner so I don't think I'll be able to find the brand.

Comment: Are the glass doors sagging a little at the middle? Have you tried bending the clips (it would be best to do that with them off the glass)?

Comment: Hi Andrew,

Thanks for responding, I had a very similar thought of bending the clips. It turns out that they've become somewhat brittle over the years and I snapped one of them. I hesitate to do it to the other one since then I won't have a guide for trying to find a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the responses got me thinking along the lines of something else I could use in place of the original.

It turns out that the Hilman clamp fasteners that are in the hardware section at some big box hardware stores are about the right size and shape and with a little bending do the job perfectly.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to help. Your responses got me thinking along the right lines to find something that would work to hold the doors close while still looking OK.